# How to crawl a website using wget until 300 html pages are saved

Tags: wget

I want to crawl a website recursively using wget in Ubuntu and stop it after 300 pages are downloaded. I only save the html file of a page. Currently, this is the command I am using:

```
wget -r --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./LOCAL-DIR WEBSITE-URL --follow-tags=a
```

I want the code to somehow count the html files inside LOCAL-DIR and if the counter shows 300, stop the crawling. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: This isn't about Ubuntu. I can't image any reason to do this... unless you're into hacking. Am I wrong?

Comment: @heynnema First of all, I do not see how my interests are relevant! Second, you are wrong. I am trying to make a question answering system and I need to crawl a lot of websites. For each website I need a number of pages to be crawled. So, please help me with answering the question instead of accusing me of having bad intentions!

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

1. background your `wget` command and record its PID (`$!`)
2. set up an `inotifywatch` on the receiving directory to count files
3. kill the `wget` process when the count exceeds a threshold

To illustrate, using a shell function to simulate the recursive `wget`:

```
#!/bin/bash

local_dir=tmp

wgetcmd() {
  local i=0

  while :
  do 
    # simulate page download
    echo "Downloading... $((++i))"
    touch "$local_dir/file${i}.html"
    sleep 2
  done
}

wgetcmd & pid=$!

j=1
while kill -s 0 $pid && read path action file
do
  if (( ++j >= 30 )); then
    echo "Reached page limit"
    kill $pid
    break;
  fi
done < <(inotifywait -m "$local_dir" -e close_write)
```